# how to replace broken images in webpage with some error image with mootools1.2

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mootools1.2

i am running on php, mysql and using mootools1.2 as my js framework.

I want that all broken images should replace with a single error image.

How should i do this.

Thanks

Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link may help ,
http://davidwalsh.name/custom-missing-image

```
1 window.addEvent('domready',function() {
2  /* version 1 */
3  $$('img.missing1').addEvent('error',function() {
4    this.set({
5      src: 'http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/missing-image.jpg',
6      alt: 'Sorry!  This image is not available!',
7      styles: {
8        width: 110,
9        height:40
10      }
11    });
12  });
13  /* version 2 */
14  $$('img.missing2').addEvent('error',function() {
15    this.set({
16      src: 'http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/missing-image-2.jpg',
17      alt: 'Sorry!  This image is not available!',
18      styles: {
19        width: 30,
20        height:28
21      }
22    });
23  });
24 });
```